# Is this a curried function?

Tags: javascript, currying

I am studying for JS coding interviews and just wanted a simple example of JS currying.

Does this example pass as currying?

```
    function curry(a){
     return function(b){
       return function(c){
         console.log(a+b+c)
      }
    }
  }
   curry(2)(2)(2)
```

Comment: Yes, this is simple example of js currying.

Comment: Thanks all the examples I found on youTube seemed overly complex for my needs.

Comment: More importantly, you have to know what they are good for.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You have a function, returning a function, which therefor uses the previously passed parameter, achieving closure in the scope of the returned function.